# Cant get needed assembly loaded on server - Office 2010 Primary Interop

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008, installation, gac, office-interop

Built a C# Script Component in SSIS referencing Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Ver 14. Works fine on my laptop.
Now I need to run it on a Win 2008 R2 Server and that assembly does not exist.

I downloaded PIARedist.exe Version:14.0.4763.1024 from:  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3508

After extracting I ran the o2010pia.msi by double clicking. It started to run and appeared to end abruptly but without errors.

In the readme it showed what the installed assemblies would be but none of them show in the GAC. I ran this using an account that is part of the local Admin group. Didn't reboot.

Looking for a suggestion. - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue.

Looking at the system requeriments in the download link you said, we can see that Windows Server 2008 R2 is not mentioned... And it may not be supported.

"System requirements
Supported operating systems: Windows 2000 Service Pack 4, Windows Server 2003, Windows XP Service Pack 2

Microsoft Windows XP, Microsoft Windows Vista, Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Microsoft Windows Server 2008, Microsoft Windows 7

The following is also required:
Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 or higher"

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and solved it by running command prompt as admin and running:

`msiexec /i o2010pia.msi`

Answer (score -1):

I was having a similar issue on a Windows 2008 R2 x64 server where the o2010pia.msi installer seems to quit during the installation.  I even tried cnyborg's answer by running a command prompt as admin and then executing "msiexec /i o2010pia.msi".

I deployed my ASP.NET webforms application anyways and during execution of the following code:

```
_Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref templateFilePath, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

I received the error:

> Word was unable to read this document.  It may be corrupt. Try one or
>   more of the following:
>   * Open and Repair the file.
>   * Open the file with the Text Recovery converter.

I tried loading a .dot, .dotx, and .docx file but received the same error message.

After much hair pulling and Googling I found someone with a solution to a unspecific issue but it resolved my problem!

Here is the solution:

- Windows 2008 R2 x64 Server

  Create the C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop directory.
- Windows 2008 R2 x86 Server

  Create the C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop directory.

DONE!

Comment: After creating the `..\systemprofile\Desktop` directory, do you repeat the PIAs redistributabl package installation again and if so, which method would be recommended, via command-line or double-clicking?

Comment: Hi Chridam, for my situation I didn't need to install the the PIAs to get my code to work.  If you need to install it then I would suggest trying the double-click install option first and if that doesn't work try the command-line option.